# GData Error: Intermittent "Invalid root element"

Tags: java, xml, api, google-analytics, gdata-api

I'm sending GData queries to renders traffic charts for users of Instructables.com using the Java GData package. However, this exception is sometimes thrown:

```
[Line 1, Column 0] Invalid root element, expected (namespace uri:local name) of (http://www.w3.org/2005 Atom:feed), found (:feed
```

The only mention of this error I can find online is [here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataFAQ.html#invalidRoot), but I'm quite certain that our feed URL is properly formed. For example, here is a URL that we might send:

```
https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:472899&metrics=ga:uniquePageviews&dimensions=ga:date&start-date=2009-10-12&end-date=2009-11-11&filters=ga:pagePath==/id/Inverted_Bookshelf/,ga:pagePath==/id/Munny-Speakers/,ga:pagePath==/id/Zippo-Trick%253a-The-Twilight-Zone/,ga:pagePath==/id/Firefox-Pranks/,ga:pagePath==/id/Guitar-Hero-LED-Mod/
```

Strangely, this same query will work locally, but fail on our staging server, but then work in production. And even if this query fails in one context, other queries will be fine in that same context. I know that these queries must be part of authenticated HTTP requests. Could this be the issue? I am using the same Google account (same login/password) to send the queries in each case.

Comment: Sorry, no, and I've long moved on from this codebase and have lost all context. Good luck! If it's any help and you're using web development, the Google Charts API is much more developed these days and might be a simpler integration than using the Java GData APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Read what the error code is telling you:  it's telling you it's expecting a `feed` element in the Atom namespace, but seeing a `feed` element in no namespace.

This is unlikely to arise owing to an authorization failure (Google, at least, sends an error document whose root is not `feed` in that case); it is more likely to arise if the `feed` element you get back lacks a declaration for the default namespace.